# Необходимо вывести нечетные строки файла

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Необходимо вывести нечетные строки файла при помощи цикла for

Comment: обратитесь к фрилансерам, они выведут за умеренную плату

Comment: средствами интерпретатора bash долго. быстрее с помощью программы для интерпретатора sed: `$ sed 2~2d файл`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например вот так

```
#!/bin/bash
file="myfile.txt"
let i=0
    
for var in $(cat $file)
do
(( i++ ))
if  [ $((i % 2)) != 0 ]
then
  echo "$var"
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

@aleksnadrbarakin:

> Cредствами интерпретатора bash долго. Быстрее с помощью программы для интерпретатора `sed`:

```
$ sed 2~2d файл
```